# Redirect in Spring Boot

Tags: redirect, spring-boot

I have created a spring boot web app using maven and thymeleaf. I want to redirect to '/' after data is saved to database but it is printing "redirect:/" in the browser. Here is the code

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

@Autowired
private BookingRepository bookingRepository;

@RequestMapping(value="/", method= {RequestMethod.GET})
public String index() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/", method= {RequestMethod.POST})
public @ResponseBody String addNewBooking(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String email,
        @RequestParam String phoneNumber, @RequestParam String device, @RequestParam String model) {
    Booking book = new Booking();
    book.setName(name);
    book.setEmail(email);
    book.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    book.setDevice(device);
    book.setModel(model);
    bookingRepository.save(book);
    return "redirect:/";
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@ResponseBody` from your controller method `addNewBooking(...)`. With `@ResponseBody` you tell Spring to map the result of your method to the HTTP response body and so your browser displays it as plain text (you need this if you want to develop RESTful APIs with Spring). As you are using Spring MVC, you want to return a view and therefore you don't need `@ResponseBody`.

The corrected method could look like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method= {RequestMethod.POST})
public String addNewBooking(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String email,
        @RequestParam String phoneNumber, @RequestParam String device, @RequestParam String model) {
    Booking book = new Booking();
    book.setName(name);
    book.setEmail(email);
    book.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    book.setDevice(device);
    book.setModel(model);
    bookingRepository.save(book);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```